# Spring how to use domain object

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem using objects in Spring. So, we have an object (domains) `user` and another object `car`.

```
public class user{
    private String name;
    private String car;
    ...
    constructor()
    get()
    set()
    ...
}

public class car{
    private String color;
    ...
    constructor()
    get()
    set()
    ...
}
```

And, `user` can have 0..N `car`. How should look the annotation object to make things work?

Can someone write a simple demo for this?

Comment: Spring is not magic.  Also, consider learning java.  the user class above can reference exactly zero or one car objects.  It seems likely that you want to use a List<car> in the user object.  Spring will not magically assign the cars to the user object.  If you have a list of car objects in user and an appropriate setter, then you can use spring to assign a list of car objects to a user object.

Answer (score 1):

Please read and follow the Java coding standards.  Your code is hard to read.

Model instances aren't managed by Spring.  You should create new instances, not make Spring responsible.

You will create new `User` and `Car` instances for each session or request object as needed.  They should be manipulated and managed in scope and then garbage collected.  Spring will not manage those; you will not annotate them.

Comment: What? My code is hard to read? You can't read four lines of code?

Comment: You don't follow the standards.  You should.  This isn't C#.  First we make our habits; then our habits make us.

Comment: This probably should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Not true; the part about Spring goes right the heart of the question.  The style concern is a sidebar.